# search from txt php multiple line with same value

Tags: php

PHP

```
<?php
$input = $_POST['name'];
// $input is the word being supplied by the user
$handle = @fopen("somefile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
  while (!feof($handle)) {
    $entry_array = explode(";",fgets($handle));
      if ($entry_array[0] == $input) {
      echo $entry_array[1];
      return $entry_array[1];
      }

    }
  fclose($handle);
  }
return NULL;

?>
```

somefile.txt

```
a;hello
a;hello2
a;hello3
b;hello4
c;hello5
```

no when i type a, it only shows the first one which is "hello", what should i do to make it read all the a; hello&hello2&hello3. that is what im trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why are you returning after `echo $entry_array[1];`? this ends the `while`-loop

Comment: ah silly me. didnt realize that was the mistake. thanks